# how to mount an iso to a cdrom ubuntu 13.04

Tags: wireless, mount, repository, iso, cd

i'm new with ubuntu. I decided today to install the version 13.04. When i finished installing it, the system didn't recognized my broadcom BCM43227 wifi network card. So i searched online, and i known that i had to install bcmwl-kernel-source from my ubuntu cd. The problem is that i don't have a cd, but a USB drive with ubuntu (unetinboot). So maybe the only solution is to mount the iso of my usb into media/cdrom (upgrade software center says that the bcmwl-kernel-source must be in media/cdrom).

I also found this but i don't know how to install it
http://www.broadcom.com/docs/linux_sta/hybrid-portsrc_x86_64-v5_100_82_112.tar.gz

I hope you can help me!

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to mount it with **Archive Mounter**. It’s pre-installed on Ubuntu.

[image: Open with Archive Mounter]

Then you can see it under **Network**:

[image: Mounted ISO]

### Alternative

You can also install **Gmount-iso** from Ubuntu Software Center, but Archive Mounter does its job well enough.

Comment: Hi and thanks to have answered. now i'm under windows.the upgrade center said that the drivers must be on the ubuntu cd and not on a drive, is what you wrote the right procedure? can't i install the wifi driver from the link i posted?

Comment: You know, I thought it’s a link of an app for mounting ISO files. I can’t open the link (the server says it may be changed or removed), however, I’m not so technical to know about .tar.gz files. I think there should be an install file inside. Search for installing tar.gz. Sorry! :(

Comment: there are src and lib folders, inside them there are lots of file that i can't open...

Comment: Yeah, you should do this all on Ubuntu. But at first, make sure your hardware is not detected. For example, run `rfkill list` in a Terminal to list all connection devices. Then make sure you’ve enabled Wi-Fi through the connection menu.

Comment: i resolved with sudo dpkg -i bcmwl*.deb

Comment: You can make an answer and choose it as the best answer to mark the question answered.

Comment: how can i do that?

Comment: Click on the “Answer Your Question” on the bottom, write the answer, and after two days click on the tick to mark it as the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: Get from an Ubuntu's CD-DVD-USB Drive these files: dkms.deb (/pool/main/d/dkms) and bcmwli.deb (/pool/restricted/b/bcmwli). Then copy them on your Ubuntu Desktop. So open terminal and type:

```
cd Desktop/
```

or

```
cd desktop/
```

and then

```
sudo dpkg -i dkms*.deb

sudo dpkg -i bcmwli*.deb
```